# Get the last value of a column in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle 10g and I want to get the last value of specified column of a table based on some conditions. How to write the query for this in NetBeans for exp. Suppose I want to get the last value of `balance` column where `student id = 101`, `class = nursery` and `academic year = 2014`

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no last row in a table.

Comment: That being said, if you can articulate an ordering which places a certain record last, then maybe a query can be written.

Comment: You say "specified" table and "some" condition.  Who's specifying the table and naming the condition here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ROWNUM`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) to limit the number of results.

And to get the `last` records, you have to `sort` the records based on your condition.

An example of your query can be.

```
select * from (
    select * from student 
    where class='nursery' and academic_year=2014
    order by id desc
) where ROWNUM=1;
```

This will sort the records in `DESCENDING` order by `id` and returns the `first record` from the results.

**Updated**

As mentioned by [MT0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0) in comments, `ROWNUM` value will be assigned before `ORDER BY` clause. Thus, may result in incorrect result.

I have corrected the above query, and now

1. subquery will sort the records in descending order of `id`.
2. selection will be done on the results. `(WHERE ROWNUM=1)`

Comment: `ROWNUM` is assigned before the `ORDER BY` clause is applied. This will **NOT** get the row with the latest `ID` but will get the first row the database finds that matches the `WHERE` clause and all subsequent rows will be discarded - only after that will the `ORDER` clause be applied (ordering a single row).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with oracle 10g you can use the LAST_VALUE function. Assuming if "balance" per student can be ordered by some time variable, and if student_id is unique within academic_year, class:

```
   SELECT student_id, academic_year,class, LAST_VALUE(balance) OVER
   (PARTITION BY student_id, academic_year,class ORDER BY time_variable desc) AS 
   last_balance from student where student_id ...;
```

The first row of this query contains the most recent value of "balance" (last_balance)

Answer (score 0):

I am using a little bit different query. Don't know why, but always put rownum in subquery as a new column

```
select m.* from (
       select rownum as rn, t.* from student t
       where t.class='nursery' and t.academic_year=2014
       order by t.di desc) m
where m.rn=1;
```